# How to Authorise swagger UI links using python?

Tags: python-3.x, flask, swagger, swagger-ui

I have the following configuration for swagger in the flask app.

```
def configure_swagger(app):
    """ Swagger Configuration for APP """
    app.config["SWAGGER"] = {"title": "Swagger-UI", "uiversion": 3}

    swagger_config = {
        "headers": [],
        "specs": [
            {
                "endpoint": "apispec_1",
                "route": "/apispec_1.json",
                "rule_filter": lambda rule: True,  # all in
                "model_filter": lambda tag: True,  # all in
            }
        ],
        "static_url_path": "/flasgger_static",
        "swagger_ui": True,
        "specs_route": "/swagger/",
    }
   SWAGGER_TEMPLATE = {
        
        "securityDefinitions": {"APIKeyHeader": {"type": "apiKey", "name": "Authorization", "in": "header"}}}
   swagger = Swagger(app,config=swagger_config,  template=SWAGGER_TEMPLATE)
```

Plus I have a `configure_hook(app)` configuration which before sending to any API does a *token validation*.

```
def configure_hook(app):
    """ Configure before request hook """

    @app.before_request
    def before_request():
        header = request.headers.get('Authorization')
        token = header.split(" ")[-1]
        TokenValidation(token).validate_token()
        return None
```

In the setup of the app `setup.py`, I have added both configurations if `SSO` is enabled.

```
def setup_app(app, config=None):
    if os.getenv('SSO') == "ENABLE":
         configure_swagger(app)
         configure_hook(app)
    return app
```

In my health check, at the endpoint `/healtz` . I need the swagger UI to be automatically authorised with the token.
The endpoint function is given below.

```
@api.route("/healtz")
@swag_from("Swagger/healtz_new.yml")
def healtz():
    return_dict = {"App Version": "1.0.0", "Status": "Healthy"}
    return return_dict
```

The Yaml file `healtz.yml` :

```
summary: "Health Check"
description: "Give the info in json"
consumes:
- "application/json"
produces:
- "application/json"
responses:
  405:
    description: "Invalid input"

 # use the same name as above
security:
- APIKeyHeader: [ 'Authorization' ]
```

But whenever I am trying to load the swagger UI by calling http://0.0.0.0:8086/swagger I am getting unauthorised error, same when I call for http://0.0.0.0:8086/healtz.

I Ideally want all the endpoints in the swagger UI to be programmatically authorized using the token passed in the headers. I went through the documentation and tried adding the bearer tokens but it is not working.